# RBAC: control access by several attributes

Tags: authorization, yii2, access-control, rbac, abac

Models(tables):

- Item(id, name, category_id, status_id)
- Category(id, name)
- Status(id, name)

I need to restrict access to Items by exact Category and exact Status.

Situation 1.

Role1 should have access to Items with categories with ids 1 and 3, but Role2 to Items with categories with ids 2 and 4.

Situation 2.

Role should have access to Items:
    with Category 1, but only those that have Status 5 or 6
    with Category 2, but only those that have Status 7 or 8

Categories and statuses can be created and deleted.

How to implement such access control in RBAC concept?

For Situation 1 my idea was to dynamicly create permissions with names like "accessItemWithCategory_{$categoryId}" and assign it to appropriate Role and than check user if he can("accessItemWithCategory_{$categoryId}"). it works but just dont feels right.

For Situation 2 if continue such approach, i get permissions like "accessItemWithCategory_{$categoryId}_Status_{$statusId}" and it just ugly and extremely unflexible.

If dont use ids in permission names than what? i can use simple permission "accessItem" with Rule that check extra table with role and Item parameters that will allow role to access Item? But it means moving authorizaition control outside RBAC and hell with role hierarchy support.

Comment: Write custom rules for your permissions.

Comment: @ineersa yes, but what should i do in custom rule?

Answer (score 0):

When you need to use additional attributes in addition to roles in RBAC, you need to look into attribute-based access control (ABAC).

Several frameworks and solutions implement ABAC e.g.

- Apache Shiro
- WSO2 IS
- Axiomatics Policy Server

Typically ABAC is implemented on top of a standard called XACML (extensible access control markup language). XACML gives you a rule language in which you can express rules e.g.

"A user that belongs to a category can view items in that category".

ABAC is more dynamic and easier to manage & audit than RBAC is.

Comment: Hi David, does that mean I can adopt Apache Shiro as ABAC solution? thanks.